# How to select all item programatically in AlertDialgue Multichoice button in Android

Tags: android

Hi i am new to android development I have an `Alertdialog` with multichoice button
i want to set one button by clicking this button all item in the `Alertdialog` list will automatically select Programmaticaly.

but i am unable to find any way kindly help me in this regards.

Comment: You want to have the "ok" button be clicked by the program all the time in that alert dialog?

Comment: basically i want "Check All" button in the alert dialog which when click all the item in the alertdialog checked automatically.

Answer (score 9):

You can do it like this:

```
.setNeutralButton(R.string.set_all,
    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            ListView list = ((AlertDialog) dialog).getListView();
            for (int i = 0; i < list.getCount(); i++) {
                list.setItemChecked(i, true);
            }
        }
    })
```

Unfortunately, the button dismisses the dialog even if you do not want it. 
They say it is an intended behaviour:
[Link to google issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3817)

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem as you. I can see that this is an old question, but maybe I will help someone with the example solution from this blog post: [link](http://bit.ly/1if7yo0).

Basically, you need to `setMultiChoiceItems(R.array.items, null, null)` with `AlertDialog.Builder` and then get the `ListView` and `setOnItemClickListener` with a little logic and you are done. Check the [blog post](http://bit.ly/1if7yo0).

Answer (score 0):

update to [Yar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/525319/yar) answer, this will not close ALertDialog and update the list UI

```
 items.add("Select All) // 1st item
 items.add...
 
 builder.setMultiChoiceItems(items, selections) { dialog, index, isChecked ->
         
            if (index == 0) {
                val listView = (dialog as AlertDialog?)?.listView
                listView?.let {
                    for (i in 0 until listView.size) {
                        listView.setItemChecked(i, true)
                        selections?.set(i, isChecked)
                    }
                }
            }
            else 
                selections?.set(index, isChecked)
        }
```