# How to check all items in multichoice alert box by providing a SELECTALL CHECKBOX programmatically

Tags: java, android, checkbox, android-alertdialog

Hi I have an alert dialog with multichoice check box & i want to set one select all checkbox so that by clicking this SELECTALL CHECKBOX all items(i.e checkbox ) in the alert dialog list will automatically select programmatically.

Kindly help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you filling the items to list , or to a alertbox  ?

Comment: AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
  builder.setTitle("Select The Fields");
  builder.setMultiChoiceItems(items, visibility,
    new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {

     

     @Override
     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
       int indexSelected, boolean isChecked) {
      
      
      
      switch (indexSelected) {
      case 0: {
       column.selectAll.setVisible(!isChecked)

       break;

      }

Comment: hi rahul, items is a chersequence[] wher i have kept all my items ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23244437/3564556) or example [here](http://gabrielwealth.blogspot.com/2014/04/android-alertdialog-example-custom.html) or continue reading...

You need to `setMultiChoiceItems(R.array.items, null, null)` on `AlertDialog.Builder` and after that, get the `ListView` from an onCreated and shown dialog and `setOnItemClickListener` with little logic and you are done. Check my example [here](http://gabrielwealth.blogspot.com/2014/04/android-alertdialog-example-custom.html)